# Using the data retrieved from a mysqli query to execute another mysqli query in php

Tags: php, loops, mysqli

I have 2 tables in a DB one  `User_info` and another `Product_info`. What i want to do is that if i am given the `User_id`, then i will check for the `Product_id` corresponding to the `User_id` in table `User_info`. Then i will use this `Product_id` that i had retrieved to find the `Product_name` from the table  `Product_info`.

```
**Table-User_info**
User_id    Product_id

 2            P1
 3            P4
 2            P3
 45           P7


**Table-Product_info**
Product_name    Product_id

 A               P1
 B               P4
 C               P3
 D               P7
```

For example , if i am given `User_id` is `2` then i want to display `A` and `C`

The following is the code i had written :

```
    $mysqli=new mysqli("127.0.0.1","root","","bargad");//Connecting to the database
                if($mysqli->connect_error)
                {
                    echo "Couldnt connect to server";

                }
                else
                {
                    $query="SELECT Product_id from User_info WHERE User_id=?";
                    $statement=$mysqli->prepare($query);
                    //binding parameters
                    $statement->bind_param('s',$u_id);//u_id is given
                    $statement->execute();
                    $statement->bind_result($pdt_id);
                    while($statement->fetch())
                    {

                        $query2="SELECT Product_name from Product_info WHERE Product_id=?";
                        $statement_2=$mysqli->prepare($query2);
                        $statement_2->bind_param('s',$pdt_id);
                        $statement_2->execute();
                        $statement_2->bind_result($pdt_name);
                        while($statement_2->fetch())
                        {
                            echo $Product_name;
                        }
                     }
                 }



> The error i got is -Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member
> function bind_param() on boolean and  Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown
```

Comment: You should look into stored procedures. You can essentially make a mysql function that accepts arguments and does whatever logic you need. You can return multiple result sets from a stored procedure.

Comment: @Matthew Could you please give a small example ?

Comment: Check joining tables [w3schools sql join](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things you have to change.

1. First, instead of two separate queries, single query with JOIN have to be used.
2. Instead of mysqli you have to use [PDO](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo).

Having this, you will need only few lines of code:

```
$dsn = "mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=bargad;charset=utf8";
$opt = [
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
];
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, "root", "", $opt);

$query = "SELECT Product_name FROM Product_info p, User_info u 
                 WHERE p.Product_id=u.Product_id AND User_id=?"; 
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute($u_id);
$data = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
```

Here in the $data variable you have your products which you can echo out directly using foreach() or pass it in a template.

Answer (score 0):

Tried various methods , finally ended up with this.
Instead of searching for `Product_id` directly, I stored them in an array and then searched for it in `Product_info`. It does the job.

```
    $mysqli=new mysqli("127.0.0.1","root","","bargad");//Connecting to the database
                    if($mysqli->connect_error)
                    {
                        echo "Couldnt connect to server";

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $query="SELECT Product_id from User_info WHERE User_id=?";
                        $statement=$mysqli->prepare($query);
                        //binding parameters
                        $statement->bind_param('s',$u_id);//u_id is given
                        $statement->execute();
                        $statement->bind_result($pdt_id);
                        $i=0;//index of the array
                        while($statement->fetch())
                        {
                            $j[i]=$pdt_id;
                            ++i;
                        }
                        foreach($j as $pdt_id)
                        {
                         $query2="SELECT Product_name from Product_info WHERE Product_id=?";
                            $statement_2=$mysqli->prepare($query2);
                            $statement_2->bind_param('s',$pdt_id);
                            $statement_2->execute();
                            $statement_2->bind_result($pdt_name);
                            while($statement_2->fetch())
                            {
                                echo $Product_name;
                            }
                         }
                     }
```

Comment: Putting aside join which have to be used here, or even IN operator in SQL, why not to use prepared statements properly - i.e. preparing a query only once?

Comment: @YourCommonSense   You mean something like this ? $query="SELECT Product_info.Product_name From Product_info INNER JOIN User_info ON Product.Product_id=User.Product_id  AND User.User_id=? ";

Answer (score -1):

Using a Stored Procedure:

PHP:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("CALL myProcedure($userId)");

// call the stored procedure
$stmt->execute();
```

MYSQL:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `productName`(IN userId INT)

DECLARE productId INT;
SET productId = SELECT Product_id from User_info WHERE User_id=userId;

SELECT Product_name from Product_info WHERE Product_id=productId

BEGIN
/**
```

This will return ONE result set, containing only the product name

[This](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/introduction-to-sql-stored-procedures.aspx) is a good tutorial on stored procs.

Good luck

Comment: Thanks a lot for introducing me to stored procedures.

Comment: It's quite a peculiar idea to substitute a simple join with an SP.